# #<NoMethodError: undefined method `table' for #<PdfMethods:0x0000023fc7b70648>>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have been trying to create a table in a pdf i am generating using Prawn gem in rails. I have been following some tutorial but when I try adding the table to the pdf I am getting the error '#<NoMethodError: undefined method `table' for #PdfMethods:0x0000023fc7b70648>'.
Here is my code:

```
require "prawn"
class PdfMethods < Prawn::Document
    def initialize
        super
        pdf_text
        statement_accounts
    end

    def pdf_text
        text "Order goes here", size: 40, style: :bold
    end

    def statement_accounts
        move_down 20
        table_data = Array.new
        table_data << [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
        table(table_data)
    end
end
```

I have already installed both the prawn and prawn-table gems. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What tutorial do you follow?

Comment: Are you sure it should be `require "prawn"` and not `require "prawn/table"`?

Comment: @spickermann, this is the tutorial that I have been following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-A3zBeWDdE&t=498s . It is however outdated and there are not any new tutorial on the prawn table. Do you happen to know of any?

Answer (score 0):

For many years (like since 1.2, so 7, 8 years?), table support has been in [another gem called prawn-table](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table), you'll need to have that in your project too, then `Prawn::Document` supports the `table` method.  Maybe get a newer tutorial? ;)